# Avoid pandas converting 0,1 to True and False

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I am fairly new to pandas. I am reading list of sql files from a folder and then writing the output to a text file using df.to_csv and then use those files to upload to redshift using COPY command.
One issue I am having is some of the boolean columns(1,0) are converting to True/False which I do not want as Redshift copy is throwing an error.
Here is my code

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.sql'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        df = pd.read_sql_query(f.read(),conn) 
        df['source_file_name'] = output_file_name
        df.to_csv(output_file, sep='\t', index=False, float_format="%.11g")
        f.close()
```

I do not want to give specific column name in the logic to .astype(int) as I am processing around 100 files with different output columns with different datatypes.
Also df *1 did not work as it gave error for datetime column. Is there a solution for this? I am even okay with manipulating at df.to_csv.

Comment: So you are having trouble with the boolean columns only? Is that correct? You want to convert True and False to 1 and 0, respectively?

Comment: @Gusto, Yes thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution but you can check the type of each column and if it's a boolean type you can encode the labels using sklearn's [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
for i, type_ in enumerate(df.dtypes):
    if type_ == 'bool':
        df.iloc[:,i] = le.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,i])
```

Just add this code snippet within your for loop, right before saving it as csv.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works. Gusto's answer made me realize to play with iloc and came up to this solution.

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.sql'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        df = pd.read_sql_query(f.read(),conn) 
        df['source_file_name'] = output_file_name
        
        for i, type_ in enumerate(df.dtypes):
            if type_ == 'bool':
                df = df.convert_dtypes(convert_boolean=False)            
        
        df.to_csv(output_file, sep='\t', index=False, float_format="%.11g")
        f.close()
```